# Perl Mojo::DOM modifying value of attribute

Tags: css, perl, dom, css-selectors, mojolicious

I would like to modify the value of an attribute, if another attribute contains a certain string.

```
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new('<link href="http://google.com/feed/" rel="alternate">');
$dom->at('link[href*="google"]')->replace_content('http://www.yahoo.com/feed/');
print $dom;
```

So if, tag "<LINK" contains the word "google" in the HREF attribute, it should change the HREF attribute to yahoo. But instead the output is:

```
<link href="http://google.com/feed/" rel="alternate">http://www.yahoo.com/feed/</link>
```

But I want it to be:

```
<link href="http://www.yahoo.com/feed/" rel="alternate">
```

I realize the above is not meant to work (replace_content() modifies the content, not the attribute), but it is just to explain what I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `attr` method instead, i.e.

```
$dom->at('link[href*="google"]')->attr(href => 'http://www.yahoo.com/feed/');
```

it can set attributes to specified value.

p/s: [The `attrs` method has been deprecated (and eventually removed) in favor of `attr`](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Mojolicious).